# Running javascript code only once

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of js code & I want it to run only once. As this js code contains an if statement

```
if( abc.xyz && xyz.pqr)
{
//do something
}
```

Now, abc.xyz & xyz.pqr are third party functions that are being called twice by third party code on my page & hence the jscode which I have written also runs twice. Now I have no control over the third party functions. However I need to use them in my js code , but I want my code to run only once. I tried using the  code below but does not work for me:

```
var doneTheStuff;

    if(!doneTheStuff){
    doneTheStuff= true;
    //my code
    // my code fires a pixel which i can see in Charles
    // because of the third party functions called twice on the page
    // my code runs twice & drops 2 pixels instead of 1 which I can see in charles.
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If they're functions should that be `if(abc.xyz() && xyz.pqr())`?

Comment: Your solution using `doTheStuff` should work. If it doesn't, post a complete example. These bits and pieces of code aren't helpful.

Comment: Did you make doneTheStuff a global?  Or is it defined within your function?

Comment: Looks like you declared `doneTheStuff` in the wrong scope, and it will be reset every time your function is called.

Comment: its within the function

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uvepL/2/ the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Underscore.js once() method](http://underscorejs.org/#once) to do this.

```
var doStuff = _.once(function() {
  if( abc.xyz && xyz.pqr) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

And if you want to know how that works, you can browse the source yourself:

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-73

```
  _.once = function(func) {
    var ran = false, memo;
    return function() {
      if (ran) return memo;
      ran = true;
      memo = func.apply(this, arguments);
      func = null;
      return memo;
    };
  };
```

Comment: Did the OP say that s/he already uses Underscore? Or do we really need to use a JS library just to achieve that simple check?

Comment: Of course not :) That's why I included the source code for the `_.once` method. You can use it as is somewhat stand alone, or learn how it works and create something similar yourself.

Comment: Your example has a syntax error... Also you will want to change `_.once = ` to `var once = `, since you aren't importing the underscore library here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question right, but quite often what I do is assign my function containing the code to a variable and inside my function reassign the variable to a "do nothing" function - thus assuring it executes only once.

```
var doStuff = function(){
    if( abc.xyz && xyz.pqr)
    {
       //do something
    }
    doStuff = function(){};   
}
```

If doStuff is called again then, simply, nothing will happen.

**Edit**

I've added a JSFiddle to illustrate the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/4R6Nf/

Effectively this is the code:

```
var div = document.getElementById('output');
var div2 = document.getElementById('output2');
var doit = true;
var k = 0;
var doStuff = function(){
    if( doit)
    {
        div.innerHTML = "count now: "+k;
    }
    doStuff = function(){
        k++;
        div2.innerHTML = "doStuff count now: " +k
    };   
}

var items = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    doStuff();    
}
```

`div2` will output "doStuff count now: 5" whilst `div` will always show "count now: 0". Instead of `doStuff` doing nothing - its now incrementing the k variable. But you can get the idea.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uvepL/2/ I tried using ur code. does not work for me . Please see the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can do it OOP way too and avoid having global variables or scope issues:

```
function Pixel() {
    this.firstTime = true;

    this.fire = function () {
        // This code will run once for this instance
    };

    if (this.firstTime) {
        this.firstTime = false;
        this.fire();
    }
}

var pixel = new Pixel();

if( abc.xyz && xyz.pqr) {
    pixel.fire();
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this way. but it says Pixel is not defined

Comment: That will depend where did you add the `function Pixel()` and where you are adding the var `pixel = new Pixel();` If you can update your question with a full code example showing where both is. I can help you with that.

Comment: I saw ur code, but the thing is that inside the if condition ur saying window.bk_async.fire() but the if condition itself is getting called twice on the page so window.bk_async.fire() will be called twice right?

Comment: That's right `window.bk_async.fire()` will be called twice. But inside `fire()` I check if this function was run before or not using `this.firstTime` and if it was not the first time, the code won't run.

Comment: oh okay. I got you. Hopefully this will work. will take 10 more mins

Comment: I actually don't see any pixel firing

Comment: Is there a way to share a link of the page you are testing?

Comment: I'm sorry Actuall I cannoty share the link.

Comment: I am not able to help without having the full picture. But try running this: http://jsfiddle.net/DWd58/2/ and check the browser console for messages and let me know if there is output.